# Driving through Switzerland with German license issued based on license banned in Switzerland

Tags: switzerland, driving-licenses

Several years ago I was a resident of Switzerland and attempted to trade my  European but non-EU driver's license for a Swiss one. To do that, I had to take a road test which I unfortunately ended up failing -- you get only one shot at it -- resulting in an automatic driving ban and a fine (they charge you about 250 francs to put a sticker that says "Not valid in Switzerland" on your license).

In the meantime I moved to Germany, which allows driver's license exchanges for people from my country without any extra hassle. Consequently, I now have a German driver's license.

My question is: I get in my car and drive to Switzerland. The police stop me for whatever reason. Am I in trouble?

Comment: You got banned from Switzerland because you failed your driving road test ?

Comment: @Max He was probably banned from driving in Switzerland.

Comment: Actually, I don't think you're being straight with us.

Why were you fined? No government issues a fine just for failing a driving test.

If you were fined, it means you attempted to drive in Switzerland with the non-EU drivers license outside of the allotted time period (or with an invalid drivers license).

In other words, if you were caught once driving with an invalid license, that's an entirely different story and you should make that fact clearer in your question.

Comment: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: The fact that you have a German driving license doesn't matter in Switzerland if you are banned from driving in Switzerland. So if they connect the name in the German driving license with the name of banned drivers in Switzerland, then you'll be in trouble. If you have an accident in Switzerland, and your (assuming) German insurance finds out that you are banned from driving in Switzerland, you are in trouble.

Comment: It seems the about CHF 250 isn’t a fine, it’s an administrative fee for the licence application and the associated driving (re)examination. It’s payable whether you pass or not.

Comment: @gnasher729 the question is if OP is truly banned from driving or if he's mistaken. The other question is if getting a German license resets the ban. We need a quote from Swiss laws to give a good answer to both

Comment: @Max what country on the world do not ban people without driving licence from driving?

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo The question was edited after my comment.

Comment: @Max sorry I didn't mention you've written 'banned from Switzerland' without 'driving' part. The question is actually terribly worded, hard to believe it was even worse. It should be possible to answer when totally rewritten. I think I know what is the real issue, though I'm not sure what is the answer. I know Switzerland has the database of both IDs and driving licences of foreigner, and if they registered by ID this person as unapt to drive, even getting foreign licence renewed would not work, however taking driving exam in Germany should do the job.

Comment: I found this explanation of the process in the state of Zug (in German): https://www.zg.ch/behoerden/sicherheitsdirektion/strassenverkehrsamt/strassenverkehr/ausweise/auslaendischer-fuehrerausweis/downloads/umschreibung-auslaendischer-fuehrerausweise It does seem the CHF 250 are a fee specifically for invalidating the foreign driving licence (for use in Switzerland and Liechtenstein).

Answer (score 0):

You, personally, have been banned from driving in Switzerland because they tested your skills and determined you are not a good enough driver to drive there.

You need to respect their laws and not drive on their roads.

Your driving skills didn't magically improve just because Germany exchanged your licence for theirs.

Comment: Things might be different due to Germany being an EU member.

Comment: Any source for that?